# Compile Web User Control to DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, web-parts, webusercontrol

I created a `Web User Control` in Visual Studio 2008. I want to compile that `Web User Control` to a DLL so i can eventually use it in a SharePoint Web Part.

But i have no idea how i can compile or use my `Web User Control` in SharePoint.

Anyone any idea how this works?

Comment: read this..http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231548.aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649867.aspx

Comment: @GopeshSharma Thanks, but the first link is about `VS2010`. Can this also be done with `VS2008`? Because in `VS2008` i don't have the `SharePoint Project` templates. Any idea how this is done with `VS2008`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this](http://fuchangmiao.blogspot.in/2008/07/use-user-control-in-web-parts.html)...

In your manifest.xml include this..

```
<TemplateFile Location="ControlTemplates\"Your Web User Control Name".ascx" />
```

Then in your ascx file include this...

```
RootFiles\TEMPLATE\ControlTemplates\"Your Web User Control Name".ascx
```

Then call from your .cs file as

```
_value = Page.LoadControl("~/_controltemplates/"Your Web User Control Name".ascx");
```

**EDIT**

Try this...

Go to Start> All Programs > Visual Studio 2008 > Visual Studio Tools > Click Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt. 
Type the below command and press enter.

devenv.exe /resetskippkgs

Comment: So if i understand it right, all i have to do is install the STSDEV tool and then follow the steps from that site? I'm also not sure what a MOSS site is? What does that stand for?

Comment: MOSS stand for Microsoft Office SharePoint Server, You dont have to install STSDEV it is used there...you just have to include your .ascx file in the above mentioned places

Comment: I assume i have to create a `Web Part Solution (C# Assembly)`? For the rest i set it to `IIS 7` and `VS2008 with .NET 3.5`. Then I tried to open it in `VS2008`, but it complains: **test.cproj cannot be opened because its project type is not supported by this version of the application**. Any idea why its giving an error, eventhough the project is created for `VS2008`..? --- I'll accept your answer anyway. I do hope you can still help me with my error.

Comment: Try this...I am not sure it will help you or not... 1. In Solution Explorer, double-click the AssemblyInfo file 2. Edit [assembly: AssemblyVersion(“1.0.*”)] to [assembly: AssemblyVersion(“1.0.0.0”)] 3. Add using System.Security; to the top of the file and [assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers] at the bottom of the file

Comment: Is all the components of VS2008 is installed??, I have edited my answer, have a look

Comment: Thanks, seems like my VS2008 installation wasn't complete. Had to reinstall it!